# Making auto generated partial class implement custom interface

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, entity, partial-classes

Lately I've been working on a Silverlight project in which there is an auto generated class located in *`File.Web.g.cs` with a definition:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Project.Web.Models")]
public sealed partial class SwitchDevice : Entity
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the 'ID' value.
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember()]
        [Editable(false, AllowInitialValue=true)]
        [Key()]
        [RoundtripOriginal()]
        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._id;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._id != value))
                {
                    this.OnIDChanging(value);
                    this.ValidateProperty("ID", value);
                    this._id = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
                    this.OnIDChanged();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

What I wanted to do is to make `SwitchDevice` implement the `IDevice` interface. Code is located in another file named `IDevice.cs`. I decided that I will extend the partial class like this:

```
namespace Project.Web.Models
{
  public interface IDevice
  {
      int ID
      {
          get;
          set;
      }
   }

  public partial class SwitchDevice : IDevice
  {
  }
}
```

For some reason VS2010 does not see the definition located in Web.G.CS file and generates error:

> 'Project.Web.Models.SwitchDevice' does not implement interface
>   member
>   'Project.Web.Models.IDevice.ID'   PATH\Project\Interfaces\ISwitchDevice.cs

I've browsed and read a lot of web pages but I haven't really found a similar issue. Maybe I'm just doing it wrong, I'm not an expert.

Is it even possible to make this work? Thank you in advance for any tips and help!

Comment: Are you 101% sure that the generated class is also in the namespace `Project.Web.Models`?

Comment: assuming the error message was copied verbatim, it is...

Comment: @jeroenh: No, you can't deduce that. The error message refers to the class in the second code fragment. I 'm referring to the class in the first fragment (the auto-generated one).

Comment: This pattern (implementing an interface on a designer-generated partial class) works in regular .Net for sure, so maybe the problem is related to Silverlight somehow.

Comment: @Jon agreed, sorry about that

Answer (score 4):

what you try to do is fine and i do it all the times.

Make sure you have both partial class definition files under same namespace AND inside the same project. the interface you are implementing with that class will be probably in another assembly or you lose part of the advantages and will have to reference your dal anyway from the calling code and this is one thing you design could give you; isolation from DAL and coding against interfaces.

Comment: Mike, pay attention to 'same project'. You cannot have partial classes in different assemblies

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood, the auto-generated class `SwitchDevice` (the `sealed` one) is not in the namespace `Project.Web.Models` like the class `SwitchDevice` that *you* wrote is.

For partial classes to work as you expect, all parts of the class definition should be in the same namespace. Otherwise, you just have two (unrelated) classes with the same name in different namespaces, and the `partial` modifier in both of them does not play any role.

If this is true, what you need to do is move your own class fragment into the same namespace as the auto-generated class, e.g.:

```
namespace Project.Web.Models
{
    public interface IDevice
    {
        int ID { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Some.Namespace // copy the name from the auto-generated file
{
    public partial class SwitchDevice : Project.Web.Models.IDevice
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I had exactly this problem and your solution helped. The odd thing is, the cs file with wrong namespace (the one that had partial classes) was also generated by VS. Must be some kind of bug.